# measure instantaneous position of a solenoid piston?

Tags: measurement, power-electronics, solenoid, physics

I'm trying to improve speed & force of a solenoid and its power electronics strategy.

So far I can measure many variables such as :

- tension
- current
- waveform shape
- time to reach final excursion

How can I measure the instantaneous position of the piston while it is moving?

being able to see the signal as an analog value is a plus...

there must be a simple way... :)

[image]
<sub>(source: [globalsources.com](http://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/B1002063193/Door-Lock-Solenoid.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately very difficult. It is the inductance that changes predictably with position, but when the plunger is moving it creates a back EMF (related to plunger velocity) which makes it very hard to infer the inductance from terminal voltage/current measurements.

Comment: Camera, examining successive frames, with a ruler or engraved markings on the piston for calibration.

Comment: If i understand the question right..
I think you can connect it to linear potentiometer or even to a rope encoder will be better and calibrate it.. but its costly is it worth it?

Answer (score 1):

Put a high speed camera on it with a calibrated grid background. This way you don't add any mass/dashpot to your system.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Connect the armature to a linear pot used as a voltage divider and plot the voltage out of the pot along with, say, coil current on an oscilloscope.

2.) Connect the armature to the core of a variable inductor in an oscillator.

3.) Connect the armature to a mirror and use it to deflect a LASER beam a la mirror galvanometer.

4.) ...

Answer (score 0):

You could place a small permanent magnet on the end of the solenoid and use a Hall sensor to measure the change in magnetic field and map that to a distance.

Another alternative is to construct an LVDT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_variable_differential_transformer

Either way, you're going to have to put in some work to build an experimental setup.

Comment: that might be rough to try with what's essentially a strong electromagnet turning on and off

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to add a rack and pinion to the solenoid plunger. The pinion could move an encoding wheel that people less a photo interrupter to determine absolute position.

Answer (score 0):

Pop an accelerometer on it and double integrate.  Should be OK for the short period of time involved, and a motion much faster than drift, but I'm not sure if the magnetic field of the solenoid would be an issue.